# Como criar dicionários aninhados e com contagens a partir de listas/tuplas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista, dicionário

Tenho listas com sublistas e tuplas dentro. Preciso criar um dicionário cuja chave seja o nome do carro e o valor seja um dicionário aninhado com a contagem do modelo do carro. Minhas listas estão assim (é apenas um exemplo pequeno, com resultado parcial que contei no olho!):

`navio_fatiado = [[('Ferrari', 'CONV'), ('Audi', 'SEDAN')],[('Fusca', 'CONV'), ('Limousine', 'VINTAGE')],    [('Porsche', 'CONV'), ('Lamborghini', 'CONV')],[('Audi', 'CONV'), ('Fusca', 'CONV')]]`

`resultado_desejado = {'Ferrari': {'CONV': 1}, 'Audi': {'SEDAN': 1, 'CONV': 1}, 'Fusca': {'CONV': 2}, 'Limousine': {'VINTAGE': 1}}`

Até agora, só consegui fazer o seguinte:

```
from collections import defaultdict        

dicionario_chave = defaultdict(int)
dicionario_valor = defaultdict(int)
  
for linhas in navio_fatiado:    
    for elementos in linhas:
        if not elementos[0] in dicionario_chave:
            dicionario_chave[elementos[0]]
            if elementos[1] in dicionario_valor:
                dicionario_valor[elementos[1]] += 1
            else:
                dicionario_valor[elementos[1]] = 1
```

Ou seja, só consigo contar os valores, mas não consigo juntar os dicionários com suas chaves corretas, que são os outros dicionários.

Output:

`print(dicionario_chave, dicionario_valor) defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'Ferrari': 0, 'Audi': 0, 'Fusca': 0, 'Limousine': 0, 'Porsche': 0, 'Lamborghini': 0}) defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'CONV': 4, 'SEDAN': 1, 'VINTAGE': 1})`

Comment: Desculpa mas porque rejeitou a edição. Apenas estava tornando a pergunta mais clara antes de apresentar uma resposta.

Comment: Fiz a reversão para um formato mais adequado ao site.

Comment: É a primeira vez que uso o site e estou aprendendo. Não sabia que tinha revisões, e não concordei com todas elas. Agradeço sua gentileza de qualquer forma. Certamente vou ficar mais atento nas próximas.

Comment: Desculpa parecer rude, mas só estou clarificando o texto conforme a [normativa do site](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1084/137387).  Entenda o funcionamento do site lendo [O que é Stack Overflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7256/o-que-%c3%a9-o-stack-overflow?cb=1). Veja algumas orientações que vão te ajudar: [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045)

Comment: Senhor, textos como `Alguém poderia me ajudar? Obrigado.` e `Ainda sou iniciante no Python e não consigo resolver um problema.` são considerados ruídos de comunicação aqui no site. Leia os links que passei.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não precisa complicar criando 2 dicionários (um só com os nomes e outro só com as contagens). Faça tudo de uma vez:

```
navio_fatiado = [
    [('Ferrari', 'CONV'), ('Audi', 'SEDAN')],
    [('Fusca', 'CONV'), ('Limousine', 'VINTAGE')],
    [('Porsche', 'CONV'), ('Lamborghini', 'CONV')],
    [('Audi', 'CONV'), ('Fusca', 'CONV')]
];

result = {}
for container in navio_fatiado:
    for carro, modelo in container:
        if carro not in result: # carro ainda não está no dicionário
            result[carro] = {}
        if modelo not in result[carro]: # modelo ainda não está no dicionário do carro
            result[carro][modelo] = 1
        else: # modelo já existe, atualiza a contagem
            result[carro][modelo] += 1

print(result)
```

Veja que ao percorrer as tuplas que contém o nome do carro e modelo, posso atribuir os valores a variáveis no próprio `for` (em `for carro, modelo in container`). Ou seja, na primeira iteração da primeira lista, `nome` será "Ferrari" e `modelo` será "CONV", na segunda iteração, `nome` será "Audi" e `modelo` será "SEDAN", etc.

Depois, vejo se o carro ainda não está no dicionário principal (se não estiver, crio um dicionário vazio para ele).

Depois, vejo se o modelo está no dicionário do carro, e se não estiver, coloco o valor 1 (e se já estiver, somo 1 ao valor atual).

O resultado será:

```
{'Ferrari': {'CONV': 1}, 'Audi': {'SEDAN': 1, 'CONV': 1}, 'Fusca': {'CONV': 2}, 'Limousine': {'VINTAGE': 1}, 'Porsche': {'CONV': 1}, 'Lamborghini': {'CONV': 1}}
```

---

Outra alternativa para fazer a contagem é usar um [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter

navio_fatiado = [
    [('Ferrari', 'CONV'), ('Audi', 'SEDAN')],
    [('Fusca', 'CONV'), ('Limousine', 'VINTAGE')],
    [('Porsche', 'CONV'), ('Lamborghini', 'CONV')],
    [('Audi', 'CONV'), ('Fusca', 'CONV')]
];

result = {}
for container in navio_fatiado:
    for carro, modelo in container:
        if carro not in result: # carro ainda não está no dicionário
            result[carro] = Counter() # cria um Counter vazio
        result[carro].update([modelo])

print(result)
```

A ideia é parecida, a diferença é que o `Counter` já cuida dos detalhes de atualizar a contagem de cada modelo.

A saída é um pouco diferente:

```
{'Ferrari': Counter({'CONV': 1}), 'Audi': Counter({'SEDAN': 1, 'CONV': 1}), 'Fusca': Counter({'CONV': 2}), 'Limousine': Counter({'VINTAGE': 1}), 'Porsche': Counter({'CONV': 1}), 'Lamborghini': Counter({'CONV': 1})}
```

Mas um `Counter` é uma subclasse de `dict` e portanto também é um dicionário e pode ser usado como tal (por exemplo, para saber quantas Ferrari CONV existem, basta fazer `result['Ferrari']['CONV']`), exatamente como você faria com dicionários).

Mesmo que a saída do `print` não seja exatamente igual, o que importa - na minha opinião - é que a contagem está correta. Outro ponto é que um `Counter` permite outras operações que podem ser úteis (caso deseje), como por exemplo saber [quais são os modelos mais frequentes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common). Mas enfim, estão aí as soluções, veja qual é a mais adequada para o seu caso.

Comment: Estava para responder a esta com https://ideone.com/4UPv8i, bem parecido, mas depois o trabalho chamou

Comment: Excelente solução @hkotsubo ! As duas resolvem meu problema e a do Counter me dá acesso a métodos bem interessantes como o most_common. Sou linguista e essa classe Counter vai me ajudar demais. Obrigado.

Answer (score 3):

A idea do algoritmo é quebrar o dado estruturado passado na [lista](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/stdtypes.html#list) `navio_fatiado` em subunidades de informação.

Para cada elemento da lista `navio_fatiado` o imagino como um objeto `container` que nada mais é do que uma lista composta por [tuplas](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/stdtypes.html#tuple).
Para cada uma dessas tuplas a imagino como um `veículo` cujo os atributos são *marca* e *modelo*.

O código começa definindo um [dicionário](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict) onde será armazenado o `resultado`.

Para cada `container` em `navio_fatiado` e para cada `veiculo` nesse `container` verifico se no resultado já haja uma chave que seja a *marca* do `veiculo`:

- Se existir essa chave extraio o `modelo` do `veiculo` e no resultado na chave cujo o valor é *marca* do veículo somo mais um.
- Caso o contrário crio no `resultado` uma chave que seja a *marca* do `veiculo` cujo valor é um.

```
#Dado estruturado apresentado pelo AP.
navio_fatiado = [
  [('Ferrari', 'CONV'), ('Audi', 'SEDAN')],
  [('Fusca', 'CONV'), ('Limousine', 'VINTAGE')],   
  [('Porsche', 'CONV'), ('Lamborghini', 'CONV')],
  [('Audi', 'CONV'), ('Fusca', 'CONV')]
]

#Aqui será apresentado o resultado.
resultado = {}

#Para cada container em navio_fatiado...
for container in navio_fatiado:
    #Para cada veiculo nesse container...
    for veiculo in container:
        #No resultado ha uma chave que seja a *marca* do `veiculo`?
        if veiculo[0] in resultado:     #Se sim...
            modelo = veiculo[1]                                                      #Extrai o modelo do veiculo.
            resultado[veiculo[0]][modelo] = resultado[veiculo[0]].get(modelo, 0) + 1 #Na chave cujo o valor é marca do veículo some mais um.
            
            
        else:                           #Se não...
            resultado[veiculo[0]] = {                                                 #Crie no resultado uma chave que seja a marca do veiculo cujo valor é um.
                veiculo[1]: 1
             }

print(resultado)
```

O que resulta em:

```
>>> print(resultado)
{
 'Ferrari': {'CONV': 1}, 
 'Audi': {'SEDAN': 1, 'CONV': 1}, 
 'Fusca': {'CONV': 2}, 
 'Limousine': {'VINTAGE': 1}, 
 'Porsche': {'CONV': 1}, 
 'Lamborghini': {'CONV': 1}
}
```

<sup>Execute o código no [Python Cloud](http://pythonfiddle.com/naviofatiado).</sup>

Comment: A saída está difrente do que o A.P. solicitou - veja "AUDI" deveria ter duas entradas - uma pra Sedan e uma para Conv, com contagens diferentes.

Comment: faça simplesmente  `modelo = veiculo[1]` e use o médoto `get` do dicionário para saber se aquele modelo já existe ou não.

Comment: @jsbueno fiz as correções. Obrigado.

Comment: Muito boa explicação e resolução. Agradeço a gentileza e o tempo dedicado em me ajudar. Obrigado.